# Apache gives `It works` page instead of home page of site

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2, webserver

My site `www.domainname.com` loads apache2 'It works' page instead of the expected home page of moode which is located at `/var/www/html/moodle`. There is an index file `index.php` inside moodle directory but it is not taken by default. If I go to `www.domainname.com/moodle` the site homepage comes. The configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.conf` is enabled. How to solve this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.domainname.com
    ServerAlias domainname.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
    DirectoryIndex "index.php"
    # <Directory /var/www/html/>
    #       AllowOverride All
    # </Directory>  

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domainname.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Just to be certain, always run `sudo apachectl configtest` after each modification.

Comment: Ran now, but no change. I ran `sudo service apache2 restart` after each change, will that give same effect?

Comment: No, the `configtest` just needs to end in "Syntax OK".

Comment: Yes, I ran now and the output is "Syntax OK"

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: I can't find anything. Recent ones are `Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations`, `Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`, `Graceful restart requested, doing restart`

Comment: To be certain that this config file is being picked up, change something, like e.g. `DirectoryIndex "index.php"` to `DirectoryIndex "doesntexist.php"`, then restart Apache, browse `www.domainname.com/moodle` or `www.domainname.com` and tell us which one isn't found. If one is found, this config file must have been ignored.

Comment: Did this, but no change in both links. There is `000-default-le-ssl.conf` config file too. I did `sudo a2dissite domainname.conf` to disable it. The site still load and when `sudo a2dissite  000-default-le-ssl.conf` the site dows't load.

Comment: So this config file isn't picked up. Does the virtual host show up in `sudo apache2ctl -S`? Is there a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` to a file in `.../sites-available/`?

Comment: It shows `443 :  www.domainname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)`

Comment: So the site is not enabled. Rerun `sudo a2ensite domainname`.

Comment: @Jos Thanks. I added `DirectoryIndex "/moodle/index.php"` in 000-default-le-ssl.conf. Now it is working.

Comment: Is there any problem using 000-default-le-ssl.conf, it came by itself.

Comment: When I disable 000-default-le-ssl.conf and enable domainname, the site doesn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by changing the line

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php
```

in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`.

**Source :**
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Answer (score 2):

You will have to disable the example site and enable your `moodle` site. You can do this by using the `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands.
To enable or disable a site hosted with Apache, you can use the 'a2ensite' and 'a2dissite' commands, respectively. Both commands use essentially the same syntax:

`a2ensite [site]`
`a2dissite [site]`

Where `[site]` is the name of your site's Virtual Host configuration file, located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, minus the '.conf' extension. For example, if your site's Virtual Host configuration file is called `moodle.com.conf` and the "It Works!" configuration file is called `example.com.conf`, then the commands would look like:

`a2ensite moodle.com`
`a2dissite example.com`

After that, you can restart Apache by typing `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and it should work now.

(Derived from [`How do I enable/disable a website hosted with Apache? | Linode Questions`](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/311/how-do-i-enabledisable-a-website-hosted-with-apache))

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're using the default `html` directory.

Move `/var/www/html/moodle` to `/var/www/`

```
 mv var/www/html/moodle /var/www
```

Change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/moodle` in your `domainname.conf`

use `a2ensite` to enable the site or create a symlink to `/etc/apache2/site-enabled/`

```
a2ensite domainname.conf
```

Simply reload apache2 using `systemctl reload apache2`

Now this should work as expected.